# Powershell class name contains dot(.)

Tags: powershell

http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r902/docs/folder41/T_Google_GData_Spreadsheets_ListEntry_Custom.htm

`$variable = New-Object Google.GData.Spreadsheets.ListEntry` **???**

How to create this?

Comment: have you load the assembly?

Answer (score 2):

The dot is not the problem. If you think it is you can enclose the class name in '

You probably didn't load the assembly. Do that first.

```
# PowerShell 3
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Path\To\Your\Assembly.dll' 

# PowerShell 2
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('C:\Path\To\Your\Assembly.dll') | Out-Null
```

Answer (score -1):

$variable = New-Object [Google.GData.Spreadsheets.ListEntry]

Comment: That will have powershell look for a class named [Google.GData.Spreadsheets.ListEntry]